# K-statistic formula

Tags: statistics

The k-statistic is the sole symmetric unbiased estimator of a distribution's cumulants.

From Wolfram MathWorld:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/k-Statistic.html

[image: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/k-Statistic.html]

I would like to know the general formula for the $k_n$-statistic and its derivation

Comment: search up "cumulant", it's simply the cumulant/n(n-1)(n-2)...

Comment: the cumulants are all separate terms in the taylor series of the cumulant generating function